# Java why static prints out text first than method

Tags: java

Just wondering why static is always the one that will print out first rather than a method.

Code:

```
public class TestMe {
    static {
        System.out.println("D");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }


    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("Z");
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        new TestMe().printMe();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
D
B
Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two types of initializer block in your class

one is `static initializer` which is executed by the time the class is initialized

[8.7. Static Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.2)

```
A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized
```

[8.6. Instance Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.2)

two is the `Instance Initializers` which is executed when instance of the class is already create

```
An instance initializer declared in a class is executed when an instance of the class is created
```

Those are from [JLS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.2)

So `static initializer` will be called directly when class is initialized vs `Instance Initializers` that is called when instance of that class is already created thus `static initializer` is executed first.

Comment: is it really static initializer is executed by the time the object of the class is initialized?? I always thought that A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized

Comment: @SparkOn opss, it supposed to be class is initialized not object. TYPO

Comment: sometime happens man that is why i dint downvote it, +1 though now

Answer (score 6):

*static* blocks are executed when a class is first *initialized* (*initialization* of a class happens once it is *loaded* ) so they execute earlier than *instance* level blocks / methods (executed after creating an object)

Comment: +1 for being clear can you provide documentation too?

Comment: @KickButtowski - Well, you could actually try it out :P

Answer (score 2):

because that gets executed when class initializes it self

---

Also See

- [doc: Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 2):

Because `static` blocks are executed when the class is loaded.